# Track water flow based on DEM in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, gis, gradient-descent, watershed

I'm developing a program about water flow based on DEM which is in Python. There're many potential depression in such DEM. Each pixel has different water depth value and they'll be tracked according to gradient decent. What baffles me is how to determine the flow direction when the filled depression is level which means subsequent water need to fill higher elevation pixels.

The algorithm is D8 tracking water flow in NumPy array. What I want to achieve is an update array after gradient decent, i.e. array after water flow into depressions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe the GIS stack exchange may have people on such field. Water flow is one task, but filling basins is different (many exceptions in dry areas, in iced areas, and long lakes could have different levels in different parts. But when you fill a basin you will know the lowest boundary, which it is the outflow point. Flow algorithms just put "rivers" in lakes for simplicity (just using lines and not polygons).

Comment: Yes, maybe some points seem ambiguous. So I supply the conception caption below.